# SQLite - Count and group duplicates

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a problem figuring out how to count duplicates in a table like below:

| Campaign | Approved | Disqualified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| campaign-1 | 1 | null |
| campaign-1 | null | 2 |
| campaign-2 | 5 | null |
| campaign-2 | null | 3 |

My query:

```
select 
    "Campaign"
    ,case when "Status" = 'Approved' then count("Id") end as "Approved"
    ,case when "Status" = 'Disqualified' then count("Id") end as "Disqualified"
from "table" 
group by "Campaign","Status"
having count(*) > 1
order by "Campaign"
```

I would like to have a table as result below?

result:

| Campaign | Approved | Disqualified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| campaign-1 | 1 | 2 |
| campaign-2 | 5 | 3 |

...

Comment: are 'Id' and 'status' columns in the table? a query like "select campaign, max(approved), max(disqualified) from table group by campaign order by compaign;" should give you the result.

Answer (score 0):

You must group by `Campaign` only.
Also, it is easier to use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`, because SQLite evaluates boolean expressions like `Status = 'Approved'` as `1` or `0`:

```
SELECT Campaign,
       SUM(Status = 'Approved') AS Approved,
       SUM(Status = 'Disqualified') AS Disqualified
FROM "table" 
GROUP BY Campaign
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get_info = """
        WITH query1 AS
        (
            SELECT Campaign, 
            SUM(Approved) AS sum_a, 
            SUM(Disqualified) AS sum_d
            FROM Campaign
            GROUP BY Campaign
        )
        SELECT Campaign, sum_a, sum_d FROM query1
        GROUP BY Campaign
        """
```